# XULRunner could not be found in the release folder

Tags: c#, windows-7, xulrunner

I recently bumped into a problem while using xulrunner with my C# program. I had been using xulrunner with GeckoFX for weeks without fail but then I got this error message:

> Couldn't find xulrunner in 'C:....\bin\Release'.

I call `Xpcom.Initialize()` at the start and tried removing and re-adding the xulrunner folder to my project. I also clicked on all the files in the xulrunner folder and set Copy to output directory to Always. Has anyone else had this problem? I found no results regarding it on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the `Xulrunner` folder to the project and set every contents presents in folder properties as `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to output Directory` to `Copy Always` . and it will create the `xulrunner` folder in release or output directory. And you can do other way , Copy the `xulrunner` folder under `bin/release` and set the initialize path

```
Xpcom.Initialize(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "xulrunner");
```